# OS X - how to give permissions to jenkins user to run docker command

Tags: jenkins, docker, osx-yosemite

In Unix , I've to add jenkins user to Docker group explicitly so that I can run docker commands through shell step.

I couldn't find answer about how to achieve same on OS X ( mac mini 2012 ).

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vikram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working as mentioned in below ticket

https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/799

Docker documentation wrt Jenkins and Mac setup , hardly has any info.

First add jenkins user to staff group and give this group required permission to run docker commands

Comment: how do you give the staff group permission to run docker?